# Fonts are dancing around in different sizes and styles

Tags: html, css

So I am facing a weird issue with the text. Some fonts have totally different shapes, sizes. I have already used `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for the web page to prevent some fonts from misbehaving.  But It didn't solve the issue.

[image]

Attached is the code of behaving text, when I try to remove the word and type it again, it works fine. But why it is showing like that? I have copied this text from Microsoft Word with the `Calibri` font used in it. Tried `font-style: normal` as well but no luck. I was wondering what can be the issue.

**Without Issue Text**: I removed and type the text again which solved the issue for me. But I can't type them all again on the actual page.

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
p {
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>With Issue</h1>
<p>Our рrоduсt line is ultіmаtеlу aimed at promoting skin’s nаturаl rеjuvеnаtіоn process tо ѕоftеn ѕkіn, mаіntаіn elasticity, mіnіmіzе thе appearance оf роrеѕ аnd wrіnklеѕ, еvеn ѕkіn tоnе, and еnhаnсе radiance.</p>


<h1>Without Issue</h1>

<p>Our product line is ultіmately aimed at promoting skin’s nаtural rеjuvenаtіоn process tо softеn ѕkіn, maintain elasticity, mіnіmіzе thе appearance оf pores аnd wrіnkles, even skin tone, and enhance radiance.</p>
```

Comment: which browser are you looking at? did you test using other browsers?

Comment: Latest Chrome Browser

Comment: The issue is happening on every browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing English words, but sometimes you don't use English letters.

If I [examine](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) a word from your source code the characters you are using are:

```
U+0075 : LATIN SMALL LETTER U
U+006C : LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+0074 : LATIN SMALL LETTER T
U+0456 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER BYELORUSSIAN-UKRAINIAN I {Old Cyrillic i}
U+006D : LATIN SMALL LETTER M
U+0430 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A
U+0074 : LATIN SMALL LETTER T
U+0435 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE
U+006C : LATIN SMALL LETTER L
U+0443 : CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U
```

The font you are using doesn't have cyrillic characters in it, so the browser falls back to one which does.

Use the correct alphabet for the (human) language you are writing in!

You might be able to solve the problem programmatically by using a transliteration tool (e.g. [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/transliteration)) to force everything to ASCII.

Comment: Really Appreciate for your time and reply. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Text in MS word has extra information associated with it that can also be copied over when doing a copy paste into an html file or a CMS. Best practice for a copy and paste would be to try an intermediate text editor (like TextEdit for Mac or Note for Windows) or to convert the document to plain text before copying and pasting in your code.